# Счетчик дней обратного отсчета

Tags: android

Нужно создать в программе таймер обратного отсчета (только дни) до события.

То есть:
До выпуска новой версии осталось 5 дней, чтобы каждый раз, когда пользователь заходит, ему высвечивалась эта информация.

Нашел [тут](https://vk.com/wall-53836049_1096) информацию о том, как это сделать.
Только, если выйти из программы, заново начинается сброс. 
В комментариях указано, что нужен сервис.
Что это за сервис, как его сделать?
Очень прошу подсказать, так как в Android  я новичок.

Comment: Откуда вы получаете дату до которой надо считать дни?

Comment: Ну вы знаете, что релиз 1 августа, а откуда об этом узнает приложение? Дедлайны .. дата на сервере .. СМСки рассылать будете ?

Answer (score 1):

Надо просто вычислить сколько осталось дней до даты релиза от текущей даты, зачем сервис если пользователь открывает приложение.

вот держите пример, для activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ... всякий дурацкий код
        long dataReliza=new GregorianCalendar(2015, 07, 28).getTimeInMillis();
        String toRelizeDayStr=getDaysToEvent(dataReliza,null,this);
        Toast.makeText(this, "До релиза осталось "+toRelizeDayStr+" дней." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

public static String getDaysToEvent(long datetime, long now, Context context) {

        Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        if (now != 0) {         mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(now);         }

        mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        long daynow = mCalendar.getTimeInMillis();

        // обнуление datetime
        mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(datetime);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        long daytime = mCalendar.getTimeInMillis();     

        int sysDay = (int) (daynow / 86400000);// 1000*60*60*24= 86400000
        int dateDay = (int) (daytime / 86400000);
        // Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage()

        int raznost = Math.abs(sysDay - dateDay);

        String raznostText;

        if (raznost < 10)
            raznostText = " " + Integer.toString(raznost) + " ";
        else
            raznostText = Integer.toString(raznost);

        return raznostText;
    }
```

Comment: Думаю имя метода, вроде `getDaysToEvent()` будет более уместно. Транслитерация с русского в именах пугает :)

Comment: Это потому , что ты не работал 10 лет 1С программистом,  как я  :)

Comment: @pavlofff, я сам её(дату) хочу установить.

Comment: @pavlofff, к примеру, я знаю, что новая версия выйдет 1 августа. Тогда я в приложении хочу написать, что "Осталось 8 дней до выхода", а завтра, при входе, чтобы было написано "осталось 7 дней" и так далее. Это возможно?

Comment: дак ты вместо dataReliza - переменной поставь твою дату. Я же тебе написал функцию которая будет говорить сколько дней осталось до заданной даты.

Comment: @Evgeny Karavashkin, как именно это сделать? Прошу прощения за нубские вопросы, я совсем новичок в разработке:)

Comment: dataReliza=new GregorianCalendar(2015, 07, 28).getTimeInMillis();

Comment: @Evgeny Karavashkin, я еще раз прошу прощения за беспокойство. А в чем может быть причина? Вроде, всё импортировал, но все равно не определяется, красным выделено.  http://firepic.org/?v=2.2015-07-27_e3zso7mpu7hz.jpg - как на фото.

Comment: @user186295 Java - язык с строгой типизацией. Укажите тип создаваемой переменной

Comment: @pavlofff, int=(dataReliza);        Я на верном направлении?

Comment: @user186295 НЕТ. Лучше всего вам прочитать какой то курс по Java. С такими знаниями вы не сможете продолжать программировать, пока кто то не будет делать это за вас.

Comment: на верном :) только не int, a long :)))